# Dynamically wait for jenkins' sub jobs to finish and set parent job status based on their statuses

Tags: jenkins, groovy, post-build

I have a groovy post-build script that dynamically calls for a sub jobs based on an input file `file.txt`:
Each line in `file.txt` is then passed into a new subjob.

```
import hudson.model.*
def file = manager.build.getParent().getWorkspace().child('file.txt')
def lines = file.readToString().split('\r\n')
lines.each { String line ->  
      childProjectName = "childProjectName"
      job = manager.hudson.getItem(childProjectName)
      def params = new StringParameterValue('Input_Variable', line) 
      def paramsAction = new ParametersAction(params) 
      def cause = new hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(manager.build)
      def causeAction = new hudson.model.CauseAction(cause)
      def waitingItem = manager.hudson.queue.schedule(job, 0, causeAction, paramsAction)
}
```

I'd like to block the parent job until all sub jobs are done and based on their statuses pass/fail the parent job.
Any idea how to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

one of your options is to create jenkinsFile pipeline script.
by using the parallel and you have the ability to control what will happen on each of the tasks failures and what if all fails.